# Let $G$ be a finite group such that $3\nmid |G|$ and $a, b\in G$. Prove: If $a^3 = b^3$, then $a = b$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group such that $3\nmid |G|$ and $a, b \in G$. Prove: If $a^3 = b^3$ then $a = b$.

My thoughts:

If $3 \nmid |G|$, there must be $0 < r < 3$ such that $|G| = 3m + r$.

Now we get:

$$\begin{align}
a^3 = b^3 &\implies a^{3m} = b^{3m}\\
&\implies a^{3m+r} = b^{3m}\cdot a^r\\
&\implies e = b^{3m}\cdot a^r\\
&\implies a^{-r} = b^{3m}.
\end{align}$$

But that seems useless as  I could not go any further. Any hints?

Comment: Since 3 doesn’t divide |G|, the two numbers are actually relatively prime. Hence, 1 is a linear combination with integer coefficients of 3 and |G|. Therefore…

Comment: Presumably, you mean finite group, and $3\not\mid |G|.$

Comment: Hint: This works if you replace $3$ with $p$ prime, but it is not always true nonprimes, unless you change “not divisible by” with another condition..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $3\nmid |G|$, we have that $\gcd(3,|G|)=1$, so, therefore, by Bézout's Theorem, there exist $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ such that $3x+|G|y=1$. Suppose $a^3=b^3$. We have $a^{|G|}=e=b^{|G|}$. Now

$$\begin{align}
a&=a^1\\
&=a^{3x+|G|y}\\
&=(a^3)^x(a^{|G|})^y\\
&=(b^3)^x(b^{|G|})^y\\
&=b^{3x+|G|y}\\
&=b^1\\
&=b.
\end{align}$$